# Nilpotency of formal series over noetherian ring - I have doubt.

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian, nilpotence

I have the following exercise:

> $A$ is a Noetherian ring. Prove that every $f$ belonging to the ring of formal series over $A$ is nilpotent if and only if all its coefficients are nilpotent.

I did a implication from nilpotency to nilpotency of each coefficient - that does not require noetherianity. In the second way the implication should require noetherianity.
I did it that way: the ring is Noetherian, so every ideal contains a power of its radical. So the zero ideal contains a power of its radical, so there exist $k$, a natural number, such that $k$ is maximal degree of nilpotency in $A$. Therefore, if every coefficient of $f$ is nilpotent, then $f^k$ is nilpotent. Am I right?

Comment: Please write your posts using MathJax in the future

Comment: To be clear about your notation, when you say $k$ is the maximal degree of nilpotency in $A$, do you mean $k$ is the least natural number such that $a^k=0$ for all $a$ nilpotent in $A$?

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly that.